# Why does my autoencoder not reconstruct RGB images as it should and in BGR form?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

An autoencoder is a combination of two CNN's and can take an image as an input. One CNN reduces the image into a very small representation and the second CNN takes this small representation and tries to reconstruct the original image (i.e. does the opposite of the first CNN).

I have constructed this autoencoder, but my issue is in my reconstruction of RGB images because with greyscale images it works completely fine. My guess is the way I am pre-processing my images but I haven't seemed to find a fix. I am using here opencv and I know that it reads images in a BGR form rather than RGB. Below shows my code and the pre-processing elements in the beginning. I have used the conversion of BGR to RGB via cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB, but for some reason when I plot the 'representation' and the reconstruction later on I don't get RGB images, I still get a BGR representation (blue-ish colour). Would anyone know why?

```
def get_input(path):
    """get specific image from path"""
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    return img

x = []
y = []
#image path is just the path to obtain the images 
for file_path in img_path:
    input = get_input(file_path)
    input = cv2.resize(input,(768,512))
    input = cv2.cvtColor(input, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    input.astype('float32') / 255.0 - 0.5
    x.append(input)
    y.append(input)
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,512,768,3)
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1,512,768,3)
y_train = x_train.reshape(-1,512,768,3)
y_test = x_test.reshape(-1,512,768,3)

input_layer = Input(shape=(512,768,3))

x = Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(input_layer)    
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding ='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding ='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding ='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
latent_view = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding ='same')(x)

# decoding architecture

x = Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(latent_view)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
# x = Cropping2D([[0,1],[0,1]])(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
# x = Cropping2D([[0,1],[0,1]])(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(32,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
output_layer = Conv2DTranspose(3,(3,3), padding ='same')(x)
```

Edit:
Here is the rest resulting to plot:

```
model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                epochs=30,
                batch_size=16,
                validation_data=(x_test, y_test)).history

# compile the latent model
model_latent = Model(input_layer, latent_view)
model_latent.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
preds = model_latent.predict(y_test)
pred = model.predict(y_test)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
for i in range(5):
    # Display original
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 5, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i])
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    
    # Display latent space
    ax = plt.subplot(3,5, i+1+5)
    plt.imshow(preds[i,:,:,i])
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    
    # Display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 5, i + 1 + 5+5)
    plt.imshow(pred[i])
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Comment: How do you plot the resulting image? Does your plotting function assume bgr or rgb input?

Comment: most likely here is your error-> input.astype('float32') / 255.0 - 0.5

Comment: hi @Micka I have posted an edit for you

Comment: @thesigmoidinfinity why?

Comment: I'm curious to see pictures :) -- mind your channel order!! opencv gives you HW**C** but your network probably wants **C**HW, at least the conv2d probably assume that the convolution ranges of the last two dimensions... perhaps you can pass some parameter that changes this? if not, you'll have to stick to converting NHWC to NCHW

Comment: @SQB considering what happens in ReLU activation... + the output range of batch normalization ... so your model input has pixels in range -0.5 to 0.5 and output only has a range of >0...so your training loss would never get better...and because of this cutoff...you are just observing some weird outputs [as far as i understand your model]

Comment: Can you provide some test images?

Comment: @stateMachine due to some confidentiality reasons I an unable to share these pictures but using the code I provided you should be able to see for yourself!